# Why does my app crash when trying to login (firebase login)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios14

> Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Stylor.LoginViewController
> LoginButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x147d0a8f0'

Code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passwordTextField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Hide Keyboard (G:UIViewController - F:dismissKeyboard.swift)
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTapped()
    self.hideKeyboardOnSwipeDown()
    self.hideKeyboardOnSwipeUp()
    
    
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: Disable Rotation of UIViewController
override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
       return false
}


@IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    // Validate the input
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, email != "",
          let password = passwordTextField.text, password != "" else {
        
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: "Login Error", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        
        alertController.addAction(okayAction)
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        return
    }
    
    // Register the user account on Firebase
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Login Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            
            alertController.addAction(okayAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            return
        }
        
        // Dismiss Keyboard
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        
        
        // Present the MainTabBarViewController
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainTabBarViewController")   
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        self.present(vc, animated: true)
        
    })
}
}
```

When i create a user with firebase it works normally, but when i try to login with the same credentials it crashes and gives an error above. Thank you for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
@IBAction func LoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
```

To

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed it but its still gives me the same error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Stylor.LoginViewController LoginButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14ae0a340'.    I changed it to LoginButton but the error still shows LoginButtonTapped.

Comment: you have 2 actions associated with your button `LoginButton ` and `LoginButtonTapped ` please remove 1 of them and leave the other with the same name as in IB to be in code